# Compare predictet image class to actual image class with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am training a keras model to recognise images of cats, dogs and horses.

So far, I have one-hot-encoded my data (since this is a multi-class classification problem), trained my model and called the predictions.

```
def read_and_process_images(list_of_images):
X = [] #images
y = [] #labels

for image in list_of_images:
    try:
        X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR),(nrows, ncolumns), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        if 'dog' in image:
            y.append(0)
        elif 'cat' in image:
            y.append(1)
        elif 'horse' in image:
            y.append(2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

return X, y
```

...

```
X_test, y_test = read_and_process_images(test_imgs)
x = np.array(X_test)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

i = 0
text_labels = []

plt.figure(figsize = (30,20))
for batch in test_datagen.flow(x, batch_size = 1):
    pred = model.predict(batch)
    print(np.argmax(pred))
    if np.argmax(pred) == 0 :
        text_labels.append('dog')
    elif np.argmax(pred) == 1:
        text_labels.append('cat')
    else:
        text_labels.append('horse')
    plt.subplot(5 / columns + 1, columns, i+1)
    plt.title('I think this is a ' + text_labels[i])
    imgplot = plt.imshow(batch[0])
    i += 1
    if i % 10 == 0:
         break

 plt.show()
```

The model seems to be working very well. I usually get between 7-10 correct predictions, depending on the batch size. However, I do not understand how model.predict chooses the batches, and I am therefore unable to compare the actual value to the predicted value. When I try to do the following:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
```

the confusion matrix that I get is completely nonsensical (for example it tells me that it only got one cat correct, but I can clearly see with some batches that it got many more correct). Could someone explain to me, how the .predict function goes about choosing its batches, and how I can successfully compare the predicted values to the actual test values? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, predict does not "choose its batches", the predictions given corresponds 1:1 in the same order as the input data. If you give it image of dog, cat, dog, you would get prediction of dog, cat dog, in the exact same order.

Comment: But that is precisely what doesn't happen. I have structured the test data so taht the first 440 images are cats, the second 440 are dogs and the last 440 are horses. However, when I run the second for loop, I get random images and they change with every run. I don't understand what is happening there.

Comment: You should add more information, a self-containing example that reproduces the problem, because I don't see how that can be happening. Its very likely a problem in your code or model.